# Run a command which is a infinite loop on the server then after 1 minute kill using ssh python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote the code for making the ssh connection. The connection is successful I am executing the command of `gstreamer` which run endlessly. I need to kill it after 5 minutes and execute another pipeline.

```
  def execute_pipeline(self,):
        print("-------------")
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh_client.exec_command(
            command='ls -ll')
        for cfg in config.serial_pipeline:
            stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh_client.exec_command(
                command='/media/gst %s' % cfg)
            self.ssh_client.exec_command(command="killall -9 gst")
            print(stderr.readlines())
            self.execute_disply_pipe()

            logcreator.log_writer(stdout, cfg)
```

if the first command is executed then it will not able to execute the next line how to process the things in an asynchronous way?

Comment: Run the first command in the background. after putting `sleep 60` then run the kill command

Answer (score 1):

Run `gstreamer` command in the background `/media/gst %s &` after that put sleep command

```
 def execute_pipeline(self,):
        print("-------------")
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh_client.exec_command(
            command='ls -ll')
        for cfg in config.serial_pipeline:
            stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh_client.exec_command(
                command='/media/gst %s &' % cfg)
            self.ssh_client.exec_command(command="sleep 60")
            self.ssh_client.exec_command(command="killall -9 gst")
            print(stderr.readlines())
            self.execute_disply_pipe()

            logcreator.log_writer(stdout, cfg)
```

Use kill gst process use this command

```
"ps | grep gst | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -2 $1"
```

Comment: if i run in the background using & can i get the log the in the stdout. readlines() . because i want to read the log the. i will assume the pipeline ran perfectly or with errors like validation

Comment: i used timeout 1m  /media/gst